# Using setUTChours to handle user timezone difference

Tags: javascript, timezone

I'm trying to create a simple piece of javascript that will set my opening hours via setUTC, and then pass through a users time accessing a page and declare whether they're accessing it in my opening or closing hours.

When I run this attached to my page, I'm constantly getting the message 'I'm not currently available'.

> var currentDate = new Date(); var currentHour =
> currentDate.getHours(); console.log(currentHour);
>
> var openTime = new Date(); openTime.setUTCHours(9,0,0); var
> closingTime = new Date(); closingTime.setUTCHours(19,0,0);
>
> var emailmessage = "You're **good** to email me!";
>
> if (currentHour < openTime || currentHour > closingTime) {
> emailmessage = "I'm not currently available"; }

Any help would be appreciated, I'm new to coding/JS however on reading the literature I've made the above and I'm not quite there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const currentHour = new Date().getUTCHours();
let emailmessage = "You're good to email me!";
if (currentHour < 9 || currentHour > 19) {
    emailmessage = "I'm not currently available";
}
console.log(currentHour);
console.log(emailmessage);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, I've tried this and it's getting closer to what I'm trying to do but not there.

The first couple of lines of code I'm reading the users time and storing it as currentHour

After that I'm setting my office hours in UTC as openTime (9am) and closingTime (7pm) then display a message after comparing the currentHour to my open time. Could it not be working as I've not factored in minutes?

Comment: What's wrong with the code in the answer?

Comment: It works but it might be my understanding that's wrong more than anything!
Line 1 of the code - is it returning the users time and converting it to UTC? Rather than me setting my opening hours as 9 and 19 UTC time, is that code taking the users time, converting it to UTC and doing the check against the 9 and 19?

Comment: The first line is the user time from the browser.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.